# Odoo 14 style error immediately after running

Tags: installation, odoo, failed-installation, odoo-14

I installed Odoo 14 on Windows. but when I run my localhost server I face this error:

```
The style compilation failed, see the error below. Your recent actions may be the cause, please try reverting the changes you made.
    
Could not execute command 'sassc'This error occured while compiling the bundle 'web.assets_common' containing:
    - /web/static/lib/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss
    - /web/static/lib/bootstrap/scss/_mixins.scss
    - /web/static/src/scss/bs_mixins_overrides.scss
    - /web/static/src/scss/utils.scss
    - /web/static/src/scss/primary_variables.scss
    - /web_editor/static/src/scss/web_editor.variables.scss
    - /web_editor/static/src/scss/secondary_variables.scss
    - /web/static/src/scss/secondary_variables.scss
    - /web/static/lib/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss
    - /web/static/lib/tempusdominus/tempusdominus.scss
    - /web/static/src/scss/fonts.scss
    - /web/static/src/scss/ui.scss
    - /web/static/src/scss/ui_extra.scss
    - /web/static/src/scss/navbar.scss
    - /web/static/src/scss/mimetypes.scss
    - /web/static/src/scss/modal.scss
    - /web/static/src/scss/animation.scss
    - /web/static/src/scss/rainbow.scss
    - /web/static/src/scss/datepicker.scss
    - /web/static/src/scss/daterangepicker.scss
    - /web/static/src/scss/banner.scss
    - /web/static/src/scss/colorpicker.scss
    - /web/static/src/scss/popover.scss
    - /web/static/src/scss/translation_dialog.scss
    - /web/static/src/scss/keyboard.scss
    - /web/static/src/scss/name_and_signature.scss
    - /web/static/src/scss/web.zoomodoo.scss
    - /web/static/src/scss/color_picker.scss
    - /web/static/src/scss/fontawesome_overridden.scss
    - /web_tour/static/src/scss/tip.scss
    - /web_tour/static/src/scss/keyframes.scss
```

I've already installed the npm package, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As you said you have already installed npm (pip install npm), you just need to run this command below:

```
pip3 install libsass
```

then **Restart your Server** :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this command to install libsass and sassc package.

1. pip3 install libsass==0.12.3
2. sudo apt update
   sudo apt install sassc